# What does the phrase "Don't be upset because someone didn't help you" mean?

Tags: grammar, phrases, phrase-usage

What does this phrase mean:

> Don't be upset because someone didn't help you.

Does this mean "not to be upset with the reason being someone didn't help you" or "since someone didn't help you, don't be upset"? Could you please provide other sentences like this?

Comment: My guess is that it's impossible to say without knowing the context.

Comment: Who said that to whom and why?

Comment: For example if a friend of mine was sad because someone who he though would help help him, didn't actually so he is really upset.

Comment: Commonsense suggests that it means "Don't be upset because you were left to do the task on your own".